# How to exclude fields in ObjectMapper during serialization?

Tags: ios, json, swift, http, objectmapper

So I have a simple class like the following:

```
class User: NSObject {

  var name = ""
  var phoneNumber = ""

  override func mapping(map: Map) {
    super.mapping(map)
    name          <- map["name"]
    phoneNumber   <- map["phoneNumber"]
  }

}
```

This works great when turning a `JSON` response that contains these fields into an object. However i would like to exclude a field when serializing back to `JSON`. How can I do that? Let's say I would only like to send `name` and omit `phoneNumber`. Is this possible? Seems like a pretty reasonable use case, but I haven't managed to find a solution .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you could use `MappingType` enum to handle this. It has two values `FromJSON` and `ToJSON` which you could use to create logic to map your object.

```
override func mapping(map: Map) {
    super.mapping(map)
    if map.mappingType == MappingType.FromJSON {
        name          <- map["name"]
        phoneNumber   <- map["phoneNumber"]
    } else {
        name          <- map["name"]
    }
}
```

Comment: wow this is exactly what i needed!!! thanks so much. where the hell is that in the docs? i swear i didn't see it anywhere.

Comment: i'm not sure if this is in docs, i found it few months ago when i want to do exactly like your scenario and play with its properties.